# Move a RelativeLayout out of the screen (with onTouch)

Tags: java, android

I have a RelativeLayout that I want the user moves it by touching. I want the RelativeLayout moves out of the screen (not resizing it, but hiding it). Then I tried this code:

```
// onTouch method:
boolean hasMoved = false;
ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
int slop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
float touch, move, delta;
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    touch = event.getX();
    return true;
}
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    move = event.getX();
    delta = touch - move;
    if(Math.abs(delta) > slop) hasMoved = true;
    if (hasMoved) {

        int lMargin = (int) ((touch - move) * (-1));
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
                ((MarginLayoutParams) lp).leftMargin = lMargin;
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

But it's not working properly. The relativeLayout gets flashing (the margin gets to the disired position, then it returns to the original position many times while the users move it).

Sorry for my bad english. If you wish, I can try to explain better or in another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding exactly what you are trying to do correctly, but to hide a view you can do something like this.

```
relativeLayout.SetVisibility(View.GONE)
```

or

```
relativeLayout.SetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's to hide partially, not the whole view. So, I have to set the left margin to a negative value. It works, but the view gets flashing.